# Why does the name of the arguments in the method not match when inheriting the CommandExecutor interface?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm learning how to make plugins on Paper for Minecraft. I ran into this problem(?): when inheriting the CommandExecutor interface, I automatically create a method using Shift+Alt+Enter, but the name of the arguments is different in my video tutorial.

The development version of Java 17, as recommended by IDEA itself. Plugins for IDEA are installed.

My option:

```java
public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender commandSender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String s,
                         @NotNull String[] strings)
```

Option from the lesson:

```java
public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender sender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String label,
                         @NotNull String[] args)
```

In search of a solution, I realized that Maven does not have a dependency (like) with javadoc or the like. I checked the boxes in the settings of Maven automatically download: Source, Doc., Annotations. But it didn't help.

Comment: Please show all code as *text* rather than as images.

Comment: What is the original interface?

Comment: You mean eg. `commandSender` instead of `sender`? That's just the name, that's irrelevant. The only important thing is the types are correct.

Comment: Generally, names like these are simply copied from the overridden method. Likely the video tutorial used a different version of the library, and the authors of that library renamed the parameters, or the library doesn't contain debug information, so IntelliJ derives it from the class names of the parameter types instead of using the original parameter names. This is really an inconsequential difference, and not something you should get hung up on.

Comment: If you don't like the parameter names, just change them? Javac might erase them anyways (depending on the flags).